# Were There Any Real Green Orion Women in Trek Before the Series "Enterprise"?

Tags: star-trek

In the original *Star Trek* series, in the episode *The Menagerie*, we see Captain Pike go through a number of different illusions created by the Talosians.  In one of them he's watching Vina, the woman that he's been brought to be paired with, on display, as a green skinned Orion slave girl.  This is not a real Orion, it's Vina, looking like one.

Are there any appearances in the original *Star Trek* of any green Orion women?  Or even any men?  How about in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*?  Or *Deep Space Nine* or *Voyager*?

As best I can remember, the only appearance of any green skinned Orion, male or female, was only in *Enterprise* when three of them tried to take over the *Enterprise*.  Is this the first time an actual Orion showed up in Trek?

Comment: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Orion

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Yes**, just one that fits those criteria in the live-action series:  [Marta](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Marta) was a female Orion inmate who appeared in TOS 3x16, [Whom Gods Destroy](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Whom_Gods_Destroy_%28episode%29):

[image]

The [Appearances](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Orion#Appearances) section of the Orion page also lists 2 appearances in the Animated Series.

Comment: In the TAS Episode "Time Trap" one of the main characters is a Green Orion Woman, who seems to have given up her aggressive tendencies.

Answer (score 6):

**There was, however, a blue-skinned Orion male surgically altered to look like an Andorian in Journey to Babel (which appeared as Season 2, Episode 10, aired November 17, 1967). The alterations are the antenna and hair. The members of the Orion species come in green and blue-skinned varieties.**

[image]

> Among the delegates was an Orion spy, Thelev, disguised as an Andorian, who in association with an attacking Orion scout ship made a futile attempt to prevent the conference by destroying the USS Enterprise. Had their attack on Starfleet succeeded, they would have instigated mutual suspicion and possibly interplanetary war. Had war broken out, they would have cleaned up supplying dilithium to both sides while continuing to raid Coridan. (TOS: "Journey to Babel")

Another Orion is seen in the Mirror Universe in Deep Space Nine in their episode, In a Mirror, Darkly.

> In the mirror universe, the Orions had been subjugated by the Terran Empire in 2155. In that year, a female Orion crewmember, possibly a conscript, was serving aboard the ISS Avenger. She was killed while aiding fellow non-Terran under Soval in an attempt to destroy the USS Defiant. (ENT: "In a Mirror, Darkly, Part II") [-- Memory Alpha > Orions > Mirror Universe](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Orion#Mirror_universe)

Comment: Is it clear he was an Orion (the spy) and not jus someone "associated" with them?

Comment: Yes, he is clearly mentioned as the Orion spy.

Comment: "The Orion spy" might not necessarily mean of that race. In WWII it was normal to talk about "German spies" even if they were Spanish or Irish or whatever.

Comment: Where do you take the blue-skinned Orion part from?

Comment: You do not establish that Orions can naturally have blue skin. For all we know, the blue coloration is also a surgical alteration (or even just dyed skin, given that the "surgically installed" antenna was removable.) If you have a source, please include it in your answer. If it is just speculation on your part, please either remove it or specify  that it is unclear if the blue is the Orion's natural skin color or a surgical alteration.

Answer (score -6):

In the original series episodes *The Cage/The Menagerie* and *Whom Gods Destroy*. The characters names were Vina and Marta, respectively.

Comment: Vina was not an Orion.  She was a human the Talosians made to look like an Orion.  (Both her name and that fact were distinctly mentioned in the question.)

Comment: This misses the entire point of the question.

Comment: The Marta part doesn't miss the point.